# Titanium and PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, windows, cordova, android-fragments, titanium

I'm new to Titanium and PhoneGap and analyzing a bit the two is not possible to develop iPhone with a PC with windows using either of the two right? Well I mean in PhoneGap in the most current versions is only possible to develop without publication.
I wonder if this is actually correct and whether there is a way to make an application to one of these two technologies (Titanium and PhoneGap) Fragment as a view of the native Android devices for both Android and iPhone / iPad. Improving question, make an application to view the devices can be adapted for smartphones and tablets for better use of the screen?
If yes there is some example code and/or source of research?

Comment: If you do not have a Mac, you will not be able to put a iOS app on the App Store. There are various ways around the other steps, but no matter what, only a Mac can deploy to the App Store.

Answer (score 3):

PhoneGap has an offering called [PhoneGap build](https://build.phonegap.com/) which just came out of beta. It lets you build your apps in the cloud without a Mac.

You might still need a Mac for certificate (p12 bundle) generation or you can use a service like [Mobundler](http://mobundler.com).

For Titanium, a recent service called [Foundry22](http://foundry22.com) lets you build your apps without a Mac or any native SDKs installed locally. You just need [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-studio/) and a hosted Git repo.

Comment: Thanks friend for the help on the sites, I will analyze each one and study the functioning of each. Friend, I can in each subject only to the Apple Store with a PC with Windows and with the help of these sites (PhoneGap Build + Mobundler and Foundry22 for Titanium)? Only now needed to aid on an example or source of studies to deploy a fragment view native android that works for iphone using Titanium and PhoneGap. I checked on the internet but very little explanation about it.
Thank you!